# Issue using CoreData in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

So I have implemented CoreData into my Xcode project successfully and everything seems to be linked together correctly. The code I am currently using in my ViewController.swift is:

```swift
func runTests(){

    let appDel : AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate

    let contxt : NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

    let en = NSEntityDescription.entityForName( "SavedData", inManagedObjectContext: contxt )

    var newItem = data( entity: en!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: contxt )

    newItem.test = "test123"

    var error : NSError? = nil
    if !contxt.save(&error) {
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
    }

    NSLog("CoreData:\(newItem)")
    }
```

and in my knoData.swift:

```swift
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreData

@objc( data )
class data: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var test : String
}
```

While the app is still running it will return "test123" correctly when referenced as "newItem.test" but when I try and run the app again and reference it it returns nil until set again. Am I not saving right? Is a class not referenced? Someone please help.

Edit: My code above returns no errors. When I run the app without referencing the class data in knoData.xcdatamodeld it returns this in NSLog

```swift
CoreData:<NSManagedObject: 0x79eb49d0> (entity: SavedData; id: 0x79eb6af0 <x-coredata://C40AE8E5-A846-4AC4-9A27-2FB109D6FE49/SavedData/p181> ; data: {
    test = test123; // it is only returning test123 because it was set previously, but when I run the app again and try to get the value without setting it again, it returns nil
})
```

But when I do reference the class data in knoData.xcdatamodeld it returns this:

```swift
CoreData:
```

Comment: Why aren't you checking for an error when you save? Use something similar to `var error : NSError? = nil
if !contxt!.save(&error) {
    NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
}`

Comment: Are you fetching the saved data when you start the app?  The code you have there just creates new objects and adds them to the database.

Comment: @pbasdf I use the same code to reference the object when opening the app, I just comment out the setter line and the save line and use NSLog to log newItem.test and it returns nil, how would you like me to try referencing it?

Comment: @RoboticCat I'm having trouble using your error pointer, it seems to have issues. When using context.save(error) it should call the error handle correct?

Comment: @RoboticCat What is happening can be seen [here](http://i.imgur.com/DIXt8Cg.png)

Comment: @uhfocuz: Yes - obviously you need to put newlines into the code or insert semicolons. You must format the Swift code as you would any other Swift code. Unfortunately the comments section doesn't allow me to put the code on separate lines. The `if` statements starts a new line as does the `NSLog` statement. This should be obvious.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but do you really save much by writing `contxt`  and `en` instead of just spelling out the whole words as `context` and `entity`? Code is read by humans not computers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fetch the data from the database:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"SavedData")
var error: NSError?
let fetchedResults = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as [data]?
if let resultsArray = fetchedResults {
    if resultsArray.count > 0 {
        let newItem = resultsArray[0] as data
        println("Saved data is \(newItem.test)")
    } else {
        println("No results from fetch request.")
    }
}
```

I assume your entity name is "SavedData" is of class "data".

Comment: When I use the class data for the entity "SavedData" it stops returning data. Could you tell me if my current configuration for my NSManagedObject is correct [here](http://i.imgur.com/nwZSuqY.png)

Comment: It looks OK to me, though I do most of my CoreData in objective-C rather than Swift.  Do you get an error, or 0 results?

Comment: I get 0 results when I NSLog("CoreData: \(coredata)") my CoreData(it returns "CoreData: ", but when it doesn't reference the class data, and rather references NSManagedObject it returns results such as "CoreData: {test = 'test123'}" but as i said before, when I restart the app and try and get 'test' without setting it it returns nil @pbasdf

Comment: Please can you update your post with your code as it now stands?

Comment: Updated just now. @pbasdf

Comment: Thanks - it is odd that `NSLog("CoreData:\(newItem)")` should give a different result if the entity is set to `data`.  But I don't think the newItem object is nil.  If you change the log to `NSLog("CoreData:\(newItem.description)")`, you should see something very similar to the log when SavedData is defined as NSManagedObject.  You should also be able to log `NSLog("CoreData:\(newItem.test)")` and see "CoreData:test123".

Comment: The newItem.description method worked as you said, but it is still having the saving issue. I'm not sure what to do to make it save.

Comment: Do you get an error when saving?  Or just empty results when you fetch?  Can you post some code for your fetch?

Comment: Sorry, I'm actually very new to Swift and I have it figured out now. I was incorrectly fetching it. Your code above works. Thanks for the help, it is much appreciated.